# Executing JS code from ASPX CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following in my .aspx file:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
</head>
...
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code to add data to database
// Code to execute JavaScript function in code.js telling page transaction is complete
}
```

Each time I test this, the data is added to the database. `0` or `1` is returned based on whether the transaction is successful or not. The code I'm using to call the JavaScript function is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "JSScript", "form_success(1);", true);
```

However the JavaScript itself is not executed. I've also tried `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`.

How do I properly execute a JavaScript function from my .JS file correctly?

Edit: Actually, I've just found that any function I do that manipulates the HTML on the first page (such as `divTest.InnerHtml = "Test";`) doesn't work either.

Edit 2: Oopsie, found the problem. I should have added `UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false"` to my Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for something like from the below link which gives you two options for calling your `JS function` from code behind

[Call JS function from code behind](http://www.webblogsforyou.com/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/)

Here the code is breaked down to call the js function

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "JSScript", "form_success(1);", true);
```

**UPDATE**

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "JSScript", "javascript:functionName(); ", true);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that didn't work either unfortunately :/

Comment: try debugging the code and check what are you getting

Comment: Doesn't work either, the code executes without error but nothing happens.

Comment: When I added like this `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:fillform_success(1) ", true);` It gaved me alert as `Test`

Comment: Actually, I've just found that any function I do that manipulates the HTML on the first page (such as divTest.InnerHtml = "Test";) doesn't work either. Any ideas for that?

Comment: because you are calling the `whole body as an HTML` by `InnerHTML` which will show you the body of the page. have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Oopsie, found the problem. I should have added `UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false"` to my Button.

Answer (score 0):

Oopsie, found the problem. I should have added `UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false"` to my Button.